# ¿Puedo instalar Android Studio en una computadora con 4 GB de RAM, si en la recomendación solicita 8 GB de RAM?

Tags: android, studio

Mi computadora es Lenovo y tiene 4 GB de RAM, pero en las recomendaciones dice 8 GB. Se va a arruinar el equipo si lo instalo? Es una notebook y tengo 16 GB libres

Comment: Las recomendaciones son eso, recomendaciones. Con menos, todo se pondrá muy, muy lento y será una mala experiencia. El equipo no va a estallar en llamas.

Comment: Mi pc también tiene 4 GB de RAM y no le pasó nada, eso sí, es muy lento y por eso deje el desarrollo móvil

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de contexto consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

La respuesta rápida es SI. Como te comenta @Alfabravo y @Christian, va ha correr de manera lenta.

Si tu sistema operativo no es un requisito, quizá puedas experimentar instalar Android Studio, en un Linux/GNU Debian, te darás cuenta que el sistema operativo corre más fluido.

- [Instalación Linux Debian](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=47BADug8D18)
- [Android Studio en linux](https://developer.android.com/studio/install?hl=es-419#linux)

Existe también otra opción (más practica), la cual es aumentar la memoria virtual, si usas Windows este enlace te puede ayudar:
[Aumentar memoria virtual Windows](https://www.genbeta.com/paso-a-paso/como-aumentar-la-memoria-virtual-en-windows-10-para-mejorar-el-rendimiento-del-sistema)

La velocidad de esta memoria virtual no se equipara a la velocidad de tu memoria RAM, ya que lo que hace esto, es crear un archivo en tu disco duro y ese archivo hará las veces de memoria RAM, cuanto la tuya ya este llena.

Prueba... y nos cuentas tu experiencia. Nada malo ocurrirá, quizá notes los procesos algo lentos (en el peor de los casos).

Comment: Con 16GB libres en el disco duro, teniendo que instalar Android Studio + Android, el adb, los proyectos... dudo que tenga muchos gigas para dedicar a memoria virtual, pero bueno

Comment: Gran detalle @Benito-B, aun cambiando el sistema operativo, con Debian queda ajustado...

— Windows 10: Espacio en disco duro (16 GB para el sistema operativo de 32 bits o 20 GB para el sistema operativo de 64 bits) y RAM (1 gigabyte (GB) para 32 bits o 2 GB para 64 bits)

— Debian Linux/GNU: Disco duro (10 GB) y RAM (1 Gigabyte)

— Chrome OS: No tengo una fuente fiable(Disco duro 32GB y de 2GB a 4GB RAM)

Comment: Yo con Ubuntu y 4 GB arranca rápido, pero luego a la hora de hacer proyectos y editar el código se queda el ordenador pillado cada 2 por 3, también he de decir que es bastante viejo

Comment: Yo he usado tranquilamente versiones anteriores de Android Studio con 4gb de ram y un disco duro (en concreto hasta la 3.1). Tardaba en iniciar y la primera vez en compilar pero luego de eso se hacía más amena la experiencia. Si buscas velocidad necesitaras un disco sólido. Si buscas que no se cuelgue necesitarás más ram, en especial en Windows 10 que el sistema consume alrededor de 2GB. También tuve la oportunidad de probarlo en una notebook con Linux con misma RAM y componentes de menor calidad e iba bien. Así que ya sabes. Con paciencia todo se puede y prueba versiones viejas.